# Is the money value in linkedin job offer title per month or year?

Tags: salary, linkedin, singapore

I was looking at some job offers in Singapore (I am French) and in some job titles, there is an amount of money.

I suspect it is the salary, however, I am not able to understand if it is per year or per month.

For example, for a Backend Engineer position, it says "12k", like so:

[image: back end engineer 12k title]

I am not aware of the cost of life in Singapore (however, a short trip there made me think it was quite high), but converted to euros, that makes around 8200€. For a month, it would be (in France) a **very** good salary but for a year, it is very very low.

So, is this information actually the salary per month offered for this job position ?

Edit:

An example of job offer:https://www.linkedin.com/mwlite/jobs/view/3121590292?referenceId=h1aN1XsNy7s%2BWWT%2FzWy7cQ%3D%3D&eBP=JOB_SEARCH_ORGANIC

Comment: Can you share with us the link to the job description on LinkedIn ? We may be able to provide a better answer for you based on your additional info.

Comment: Interesting question 12k per month sounds too high unless it's a senior position, but 12k per year probably wouldn't be a liveable salary in Singapore. Perhaps the 12k is for something else entirely other than salary

Comment: @Itération122442, Do you think that **8200€** is the cost of living **per month** or **per year** in Singapore ?

Comment: Why don't you ask them? I see that they advertise a dozen of similar offers, as it is through an agency, you don't risk blowing your chances. It's a fair question.

Comment: Updated thé question with an example.

Comment: Many times, these offers are for people who work remotely from other countries where that might be a good salary per year. So, ask if this is for onsite work or remote work.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that the $12K is the monthly salary for the position you are looking at.

According to info from the website **indeed**, the average monthly salary of software engineers in Singapore is about $5K as shown in this link:

https://sg.indeed.com/career/software-engineer/salaries?aceid=&kw=adwords_c_9099621460_15516767951_&sid=us_googconthajpmax-_c__g_9027645_gclid$_CjwKCAjw14uVBhBEEiwAaufYx4uwQSExYIcntvKG5M6FGC89_seCCv040xsY7U4j11G9Blen-fo2TRoCF7AQAvD_BwE&gclid=CjwKCAjw14uVBhBEEiwAaufYx4uwQSExYIcntvKG5M6FGC89_seCCv040xsY7U4j11G9Blen-fo2TRoCF7AQAvD_BwE

The info is based on 6.3k salaries reported, and it was last updated on the 7th of June 2022.

---

**Note to the OP**: If you share with us the link to the job description on LinkedIn, we will be able to provide you with more accurate info.

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/search/?currentJobId=3121590292&geoId=102454443&keywords=backend%20engineer%20golang&location=Singapour